# How do I stop a symbol being evaluated?

Tags: symbols

If I have an association A with a key of X then Keys[A} yields {...,X...} with X being unevaluated. Now suppose I assign X a value, say 2 for simplicity, then A[X] evaluates as A[2] rather than A[X] and return a failure due to a missing key 2. How do I stop X being evaluated so I can treat it as a symbolic value?

Comment: This sounds like a recipe for making an unusable `Association`, and bad practice. Is there a reason to do things this way?  Why not use strings for keys instead of symbols?

Comment: Mea culpa! I’m too used to LISP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by either using `Unevaluated` or by `Block`ing the key:

```
Clear[assoc, x];
assoc = <|x -> 1|>
x = 2;
assoc
assoc[x]
assoc[Unevaluated[x]]
Block[{x}, Lookup[assoc, x]]
```

> <|x -> 1|>
>
> <|x -> 1|>
>
> Missing["KeyAbsent", 2]
>
> 1
>
> 1

To obtain the keys without evaluating them, use the newly added (in V12, IIRC) 2nd argument of `Keys`:

```
Keys[assoc, Hold]
```

> {Hold[x]}